# Is this simplification of a proof of a lemma in commutative algebra correct?

Tags: commutative-algebra, solution-verification

Lemma 10.20.3 of the stacks project (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07RC) states as follows.

Let $\phi : A\rightarrow B$ be a morphism of local rings (i.e. $A, B$ are local rings, and $\phi(\mathfrak{m}_A)\subseteq\mathfrak{m}_B$). Then if $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, and $\mathfrak{m}_B$ is a finitely generated ideal, and $\phi$ induces an isomorphism on residue fields, and $\mathfrak{m}_A/\mathfrak{m}_A^2\rightarrow\mathfrak{m}_B/\mathfrak{m}_B^2$ is surjective, then $\phi$ itself is surjective.

I believe I have a proof of this, but my proof does not use all four of the Stacks project's assumptions, and so I worry it is incorrect for a reason I cannot pin down.

Here is my argument.

First, note that $\phi(\mathfrak{m}_A)$ is some ideal of $B.$ The preimage $\phi^{-1}(\phi(\mathfrak{m}_A))$ is some ideal of $A$ containing $\mathfrak{m}_A.$ Thus $\phi$ induces a map $\theta : A/\mathfrak{m}_A \rightarrow B/\phi(\mathfrak{m}_A).$ Since $\phi(\mathfrak{m}_A)\subseteq\mathfrak{m}_B$, we have a map $B/\phi(\mathfrak{m}_A)\rightarrow B/\mathfrak{m}_B.$ Compositing this with $\theta,$ we get a map $A/\mathfrak{m}_A \rightarrow B/\mathfrak{m}_B$ induced by $\phi.$ But we're told that this map is an isomorphism, and so both maps $\theta$ and $B/\phi(\mathfrak{m}_A)\rightarrow B/\mathfrak{m}_B$ are isomorphisms, since their composite is. In particular, since the latter map is an isomorphism, we find $\phi(\mathfrak{m}_A) = \mathfrak{m}_B.$

Now, $B$ is an $A$-module thanks to $\phi.$ Since the map $A \rightarrow B/\mathfrak{m}_B$ is surjective (since the map on residue fields is), and since $\mathfrak{m}_B = \phi(\mathfrak{m}_A) = \mathfrak{m}_AB$, we get a surjection $A \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{m}_AB.$ By Nakayama (specifically, part 6 of Nakayama that the Stacks project includes on the linked page above), we deduce $A\rightarrow B$ must have been surjective.

I seem to not need to use that $\mathfrak{m}_B$ is finitely generated or that $\mathfrak{m}_A/\mathfrak{m}_A^2\rightarrow\mathfrak{m}_B/\mathfrak{m}_B^2$ is surjective. Can anyone tell me if I am going wrong somewhere?

Comment: “First, note that $\phi(\mathfrak{m}_A)$ is some ideal of $B$”. We’ve already run into an issue. In general, the image of an ideal need not be an ideal. You would need to provide some argument for why this ought to be the case (and I’m not sure it should be).

Comment: @MarkSaving Ah, there we go. Thank you!

Comment: Although $\phi(\mathfrak{m}_A)$ as a set does not have the structure of an ideal, that's not a big deal here. Usually if $A \rightarrow B$ is a morphism of rings and $I$ is an ideal of $A$ we would write $IB$ to denote the smallest ideal of $B$ containing the image of $I$.

Comment: The major issue in the proof you offer is that you reason that if we have two maps $f,g$ such that $fg$ is an isomorphism, then both $f,g$ are isomorphism. This is absolutely not true. In general you only get that $g$ is injective and $f$ is surjective, which in your case provides no new information. The overall point is that your reasoning is not sufficient to conclude $\mathfrak{m}_AB = \mathfrak{m}_B$